# Preprocessing in Swift application

Tags: ios, swift

In my swift app, during the initialization and load process I need to check CoreData for the availability of some records and further more make some bluetooth connections before display to the user.

Is there a recommendation on how to do this? Should I write this code directly in the AppDelegate or should I write it in a different Swift class and then invoke from the AppDelegate?

I am new to Swift so your suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You should fetch the data on the viewcontroller that use that data, don't need to call it from AppDelegate

Comment: This is a question on application architecture. It's aways better to separate model and view. I suggest you to look in to some articles on MVVM, VIPER, MVP architectures for iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can do all this stuff in your View Controller i.e. your rootViewController by showing loader on screen to user and Checking the records in core data if present ,then retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be Confuse , just create a function checkRecords in appDelegate and put your code inside it and Call this function.